# Failed to acquire a SAS token when using succeeding dbt intermediate layers with Databricks

Tags: databricks, dbt

We are trying to use multiple intermediate layers succeeding each other before going to the marts layer, mainly for reuseability.
However, often we come across a sas token error: 'Failed to acquire a SAS token for list on x ... UnityCatalogServiceException'

We have a medallion structure in Databricks and are starting from the source and staging layer. If we use multiple intermediate layers succeeding each other (as a view) - often we get a random SAS token error.

```
"Failed to acquire a SAS token for list on /platform_name/source_table_name/_delta_log due to java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.databricks.sql.managedcatalog.UnityCatalogServiceException: [RequestId=*** ErrorClass=INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE] credential requested for table *** is not under dependent ****"
```

We already tried running the compiled target file in the databricks notebooks, which works just fine but it should also work without it. We also tried different materalizations but it doesn't solve it consistently, sometimes it works for a while but then not anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: This error is generated in databricks for table creating when a dbt model has a reference for a dependency model, but the model is not used in the following CTE's in that model.

For example if you have a reference for a staging model and originally use the model for transformations or testing your model. After removing the use of the model without removing the reference, this error message will be generated.